# Where is the rest of Yoda's species?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

We never seem to see any beings of Yoda's species - except, of course, Yoda himself.

This leads us to the question of where the rest of the li'l critt'rs are.
Yoda had to have parents, correct? So what happened to them? Was Yoda, put simply, just one of the last of a dying species?

Comment: There was another of Yoda's species on the Jedi Council in the prequel trilogy.

Comment: He was a hobbit once, before being warped and corrupted by the One Ri... uh... the Force.

Comment: Proected to prevent more low-quality answers.

Comment: I always thought Yoda was what a human looked like after it managed to live 900 years.

Comment: Don't forget Grogu from *the Mandalorian*- until I learned his name I'd been calling him Yoda Junior.

Comment: Related: [Is Grogu the same species as Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/273743/15742)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

We don't know much about [Yoda's species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species). Their homeworld remains unknown and even the species' true name is not recorded yet. So its fate is a mystery.

> For reasons unknown, George Lucas maintains a strict policy of keeping the history, name, origin, and whereabouts of this species secret. This policy has resulted even in certain Star Wars publications being cancelled.
>   [...]
>   Prior to the creation of [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle) for The Phantom Menace, Lucasfilm actively discouraged licensees from exploring Yoda's species, wishing to avoid confirming that an entire species of Yoda-like individuals even necessarily existed.

We don't know if Yoda was the last [of his species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Members_of_Yoda%27s_species), but, as far as we know, he is the last canonical member of them to die.

As for his parents and ancestry, this is our only clue:

> When asked what species Yoda is, Lucas has only joked, "He's a frog." In the documentary "From Puppets to Pixels", he even joked that Yoda is "The illegitimate child of Kermit the Frog and Miss Piggy".

Comment: My God!  It fits!  Ewoks are monsterous little fuzzballs that turn into wise reptiles if they feed after midnight!  Quickly!  Send them some stormtroopers at 11:59 - we need more Jedi.

Comment: @Jeff Wait ... exactly when did the Ewoks **eat** the stormtroopers? I must have missed that part -- or perhaps it's so graphic that they put it on a hidden part in the DVD's bonus features and only you were able to feed -- erm -- find it. ;)

Comment: @PeterDC Remember, Han was set to be the main course in a banquet in Threepio's honor. I guess stormtroopers taste like smugglers, when the plastic wrapping is removed.

Comment: FWIW and while not related to the question directly, SWTOR (lower level Canon) introduces two new (but historically older) of this species: [Oteg](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Oteg) and [Vandar Tokare](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare). Still, as indicated elsewhere, no mention of the actual race/racial origin in any of the dialog/story provided.

Comment: But he sounds more like Grover

Comment: He's just a really old gremlin ^^ http://67.media.tumblr.com/929e9afb05753b8f767c0108f38664ba/tumblr_nwtrdt7pYw1uipsbeo1_500.jpg

Comment: OMG after midnight ewoks.....

Comment: Yoda is no longer the last; this needs to be updated.

Answer (score 5):

As for was Yoda the last of a dying species - **NO**

Limiting to the movies itself there was Yaddle, the other Jedi on the Jedi council, from the same species as Yoda

[image]

as for being the last one to die I am not very sure when Yaddle died so I'll go with the obvious one - Grogu, who we first meet in Episode 1 of The Mandalorian (2019) which is set way after Yoda died.

Further going into Legends in Yoda's species  we have Vandar Tokare(died before Yoda) who was a powerful master who too sat on the Jedi council, and then there were -

> A fourth Jedi Master of said species, Oteg, served during the Cold War. A fifth, lesser-known Jedi of this species, Jedi Knight Minch, served the Jedi Order around 700 BBY. Although little is known about him, he proved himself quite able in the ways of the Force when he single-handedly defeated a Dark Jedi Master in combat. In contrast to the other four masters, who had all shown exceptional calmness and self-control at all times, Minch had a slightly more fiery temperament and was known to have once lost his cool when subjected to Dun Möch.

So basically we have met individuals from Yoda's species other than Yoda himself.

As for Yoda's backstory the other answer addresses it.

[Wookipedia for Yoda's Species](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species/Legends)

Comment: Vandar Tokare is, of course, a purely Legends character from one of the video games; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare., Minch is also Legends as was Oteg.

Comment: @Valorum, would removing them make the answer better??

Comment: Personally I tend to split Star Wars answers into Canon and Legends. I'd start with what we know in Canon (e.g. Yaddle died before Yoda, Yoda died but at least one member of his species, Grogu, still lives into the New Republic Era) and what we know in Legends (e.g. that there were at least three other extant members of his species; Minch, Oteg and Vandar Tokare)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Vandar and Oteg lived *thousands* of years before Yoda, and Vandar at least is long dead by Yoda's time.

Comment: I have edited your inputs into my answer, but if it can be made any better, you are welcome to do the honours

Comment: @shanu - Much improved. Have an upvote. Also, don't forget to put an @ before a user's name if you want your comment to show up in their inbox.

Comment: @Valorum, the upvote is much appreciated