# Are there any known Sith from Yoda's species?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, sith

I have been doing some reading and researching about [Yoda's species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda's_species).

It seems that, even if their species name and homeworld remain a mystery (and are [wanted to remain a mystery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6199/32339)), there is evidence of other members of his species among the Jedi and even among the Jedi council (such as masters [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle) and [Vandar Tokare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare)).

Some of the references state that

> all known members of the [Yoda's] species were Jedi

So I understand that that statement does not mean that every member of the species is a Jedi. Nevertheless, as with any other species, odds are that some of those Jedi might follow the Dark Side (unless the members of the Yoda's species have some sort of remarkable understanding of the Force and resistance to the Dark Side's temptation).

Are there any known Sith (or any other kind of followers of the Dark Side of the Force) from Yoda's species my question is.

Comment: +1 for the last three words alone

Comment: We need a Yoda guy from Dark Side too. Disney, are you listening?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Within the Star Wars canon, there are remarkably few members of [Yoda's species](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species) that we can point at. Of the six that have appeared in *any* officially licensed media ([Minch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Minch), [Oteg](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Oteg), [Vandar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vandar_Tokare), [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle), [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) and [Grogu (Baby Yoda)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grogu)) all, with the obvious exception of "the Child", have been active members of the Jedi order. This obviously doesn't preclude that a member of his species might turn to the Dark Side of the Force but there's simply no evidence one way or another.

For the record, Yoda does fight his own Dark impulses in the final episode of The Clone Wars so there's a distinct *possibility* that his species can/could turn to the Dark Side.

Comment: Yowsers - which game first, Jackson's LOTR movie or this animation?   The resemblance to Golum is ... disturbing!

Comment: @GreenAsJade hate to break this to you but pretty much everything in starwars is copied from somewhere else

Comment: Wow, I can't believe they made Minch his own character. That was supposed to be a young Yoda, dangit!

Comment: @GreenAsJade "Hard to see, the precious is."?

Comment: So this is in season 6? cool.

Comment: 'Baby Yoda' used Force Joke, a power associated with the Dark Side.