# Is there any evidence that Yoda reincarnates?

Tags: star-wars, yoda, reincarnation

Given the following:

1. [We don't know to what species Yoda and Yaddle belong](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/where-is-the-rest-of-yodas-species)
2. I don't know the circumstances of Yoda's birth
3. Yoda is very Force-sensitive
4. It is possible for a being to be [conceived by the Force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143515/how-exactly-is-someone-conceived-by-midichlorians) (Anakin Skywalker)
5. "The Child" in *The Mandalorian* is 50 standard years old <s>and might have been born after Yoda's death. (I'm not exactly sure of the maths.)</s> As pointed out in comments, this couldn't happen; the timeline is wrong.

... Is it possible that there is only ever one such being at any one time, that it is conceived of the Force and reincarnates? Is there any evidence to support this theory in the Star Wars Universe (including EU)?

Comment: It's my understanding that *The Mandalorian*  takes place five years after ROTJ so there doesn't appear to be any way that a 50 year old *'could have been born after Yoda's death'*. Additionally, Yoda's 'spirit' seems to live on as some sort of Force ghost so reincarnation seems out of the question.

Comment: yes its 9BBY at the start of the mandalorian

Comment: Since Yoda's force ghost still exists at the time of *The Last Jedi*, it doesn't seem likely that he is reincarnated 20+ years before that.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Some of us don't consider Johnson's efforts cannon, but that's not germane to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hinted, from the evidence present in *The Mandalorian*, that baby Yoda isn't, in fact, the reincarnation of Yoda Senior.

In Chapter 3: The Sin, we see a flashback of

> a young Mando's parents being killed by B-2 Super Battle Droids, apparently during the Clone Wars.

This sets The Mandalorian approximately 25 to 30 years after the Clone Wars, depending on Mando's canonical age. This also means that Baby Yoda was born *before* the Clone Wars (by roughly two decades, since he's 50 years old), and thus definitely prior to Yoda Senior's death.

Considering that [Dr. Pershing wears the insignia of the Kaminoan cloning guild](https://www.bustle.com/p/is-baby-yoda-a-clone-the-mandalorian-gave-fans-another-tiny-hint-19381972), and that the Imperial Remnant want to extract "material" from Baby Yoda (likely DNA to make more clones), it is likely that Baby Yoda is a clone of Yoda Senior, and not his reincarnation.

Comment: According to series creator and writer Jon Favreau, *The Mandalorian* takes place five years after ROTJ.

Comment: @Jeeped - I realize this, but OP asked for in-universe references, which in this case are not as precise as Jon Favreau's words. Nonetheless, ~25 years after the Clone Wars pretty much puts The Mandalorian at 5 years after ROTJ, so Jon Favreau did a great job designing the timeline for the series.