# Is Grogu the same species as Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, yoda

Is there a ***canonical*** reference that confirms that Grogu is a member of the same species as Yoda and Yaddle?

Comment: Note that "*they look the same*" or "*The Star Wars wiki says...*" is **not** a canonical reference, not matter how hard you want it to be

Comment: @Valorum If a work makes an effort to distinguish between species with sufficient differences in appearance (like Star Wars clearly does), imho it shouldn't have to be spelt out that two sufficiently similar looking individuals are of the same species. Canon does not mean it's literally said in the show, canon just means consensus of facts. Like the fact that in The Prestige there are two brothers living the same identity to make the trick work, that's the whole premise of the movie although never stated. There can be a consensus without a 100% confirmation.

Comment: @Kevin I think it can be a good exercise to track down the explicit source of information that "everyone knows", like how "Ewok" isn't spoken aloud in ROTJ but Ewoks are still well known. I agree that there's also a level of reasonable inference the audience has to make that they're looking at Darth Vader and not [his clone](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader_(clone)) or someone else in similar armor, but there's nothing wrong with looking for official sources too.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Ahsoka says within "Chapter 13: The Jedi" that he's the same species (or type of "being"):

> He was raised at the Jedi Temple on Coruscant. Many Masters trained him over the years. At the end of the Clone Wars when the Empire rose to power, he was hidden. Someone took him from the Temple. Then his memory becomes... dark. He seemed lost. Alone.
>
> I've only known one other being like this. A wise Jedi Master named Yoda. Can he still wield the Force?
>
> <sub>(Source: *The Mandalorian*, Chapter 13: The Jedi, via https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?t=40521)</sub>

(It makes sense that she wouldn't have known Yaddle, who died in 32 BBY when Ahsoka was 4 years old).

It's also made explicit by the official audio description track in Chapter 1:

> *The Mandalorian sweeps his fob around. It blinks red as it points toward a strange, floating egg-shaped object that sits half-concealed under some netting. The Mandalorian walks over to it. The IG droid steps up by his side as he keys a small panel which powers down a veil generator to reveal what's inside. A baby, the same race as Yoda, smiles up at them.*
>
> <sub>(Source: *The Mandalorian*, Chapter 1: The Mandalorian on Disney Plus)</sub>

Comment: "being like this" is ambiguous, and could refer to something other than species, like his level of force awareness/control. (Though I would expect it is *supposed* to refer to species unless the writers want a big plot twist like "Grogu's a changling and just *looks* like a whatever-Yoda-is!".)

Comment: @chepner In context of the full quote, Ahsoka isn't even sure whether Grogu can still use the Force at all. The only other things Grogu and Yoda have in common this point are having been part of the Jedi Order, having gone into hiding, and species, and two of those aren't unique among people Ahsoka has known.

Comment: The audio description is a great find.

Answer (score 68):

*The Mandalorian* creator Jon Favreau confirmed in a [Hollywood Reporter interview](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-features/why-jon-favreau-chose-baby-yoda-we-dont-know-a-lot-details-his-species-1259164/) that they are the same species.

> What can you tell us about the creation of Baby Yoda?
>
> He’s mostly a puppet. When it’s CG, we try to make him obey the same
> physical laws that he would if he were a puppet. I think a lot of
> times CG makes itself too obvious where you don’t create parameters
> creatively that allow the character to keep the same identity and
> charm. … We’ll learn more about him over the course of the season. I
> think what’s great about what George created is that Yoda proper, the
> character that we grew up watching, was always shrouded in mystery,
> and that was what made him so archetypal and so mythic. We know who he
> is based on his behavior and what he stands for, but we don’t know a
> lot of details about where he comes from or his species. **I think
> that’s why people are so curious about this little one of the same
> species.**

That'd seem be a canonical confirmation depending on how much weight Word of God is given these days in the Star Wars fandom (I haven't dipped my toe into that debate for a decade now).

Comment: Word of God is great but it's not canon since it's subject to change. You still get an upvote though...

Comment: @Valorum - Everything is subject to change. All of Legends got thrown out, and Han was made to shoot second. Why does the creator's clearly stated intent, which is also evident in the story, become more meaningful if they choose to have a character monologue about how Yoda and Grogu are definitely the same species?

Comment: What is "Word of God" in this context?

Comment: @candied_orange "Word of God" is a slang term that means "the creator of the work being discussed."  Since Jon Favreau is in charge of the show, he can say how things work; thus he has god-like powers with respect to how things work in the show.  See also TV Tropes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod

Answer (score 35):

In the article  [Sav Malagán Returns and More Concept Art on Star Wars: The High Republic Show](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-high-republic-show-204-reveals) on the official Star Wars website, this is mentioned about Yaddle:

> The Force-user is the same species as Yoda and Grogu, and she'll play an important role by the end of Phase II.

As a sidenote, I found this page by simply Googling "Grogu species site:starwars.com"

Comment: A good find. Well done

Answer (score 4):

It's not explicit, but when Ahsoka meets Grogu she states, "I've only known one other being like this.  A wise Jedi Master named Yoda."  I think that's the closest you're going to get to a canon confirmation currently.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a second answer existing if it was posted at about the same time. Feel free to edit in more information as you come about it.